# Connecting points of triangles in 3D space (help needed)

Tags: 3d

First time caller here and let me say first, I am not a mathematician, but a science / management writer instead. Today I am very interested in this article, here on the stack:

[Spreading points over a triangle plane in 3D space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904614/spreading-points-over-a-triangle-plane-in-3d-space)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3K9y.png)

What I am wondering about is:

As that 3D model is being built (using what appears to be elegant math), can we predict *which* points of each triangle (A,B,C) connects with the *other* points of each triangle (a,b,c) when building the 3D sphere illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlVno.jpg)?

Thx so much for understanding if this is an absolutely inane question :) 
Jigs

Answer (score 0):

Two faces share an edge if and only if they share two vertices. So let's say you want to determine the coordinates of the points shared by the faces $(A,B,C)$ and $(A,B,D)$. These are simply the points whose coefficient of $C$ or $D$ is $0$; they take the form $\frac{u}{N}A+\frac{N-u}{N}B$.

Comment: Thx do much for that Chris! So, there must be a calculation for plotting out each of these then as well:  tetrahedron, cube, octahedron, dodecahedron and icosahedron. Also, to create these shapes, does A and B always have to have the same length to form each? Or is that what is meant by irregular if they don't? Thx again!